# Unity3D project setup for iOS and Web Player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing a project for iOS in Unity and all works fine, but I'd like to also build for Web Player for testing purposes. The problem is once I switch platform to Web Player I get the following errors.

```
Assets/Main.cs(50,45): error CS0117: `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for `ReadAllText'

Assets/Main.cs(51,29): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Main.cs(51,29): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `string'
```

Obviously it's about unsupported API in Web Player, but how do I get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Platform Dependent Compilation" http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html
And include any platform specific code in relevant *ifs*, *elifs* and *endifs*.

```c#
#if !UNITY_WEBPLAYER
using System.IO.File;
#endif
```